# Bootstrap Popover on Image

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a list of icons, I'm trying to get a popover to activate when you hover over an icon, I can't seem to get it to work, any help would be appreciated.

```
<img class="icon" rel="popover" trigger: "hover" data-placement="top" data content="This is a popover"src="images/brandable.png"><br>Brandable</br></li>
```

And i have this in a separate js file

```
$('.icon').popover({placement:'top'});
```

Answer (score 4):

Put attributes in jquery variable instead of  tag

```
<img class="icon" rel="popover" src="images/brandable.png"/>
```

Add script as following

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    var popOverSettings = {
        placement: 'top',
        selector: '.icon',
        title:'Brandable',
        trigger: "hover",
        content:'This is a popover'
    };
$(this).popover(popOverSettings);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

this is over a year late, but i found this to work:
[Fiddler Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dalecameron/QZj5P/11/)
using this JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
      trigger: 'focus',
      html: true,
      title: 'Toolbox'
}) 
});
```

And this html:

```
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS-eTmHxgicEfq4K-sEz_X52cq56uBP2l8cr_q8ivOavSIca5TYtQ"
        data-toggle="popover" tabindex="50" data-content="test <b>text</b>" data-placement="right"/>
```

You need to allow the image to accept focus with the tabindex property. That was the key for me. Remove the "trigger: 'focus' line if you want the popover to stay open on click events...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For your code you have:

```
<img class="icon" rel="popover" trigger: "hover" data-placement="top" data content="This is a popover"src="images/brandable.png"><br>Brandable</br></li>
```

`trigger: "hover"` isn't valid html. Bootstrap help document notes, "Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data attributes, append the option name to data-, as in `data-animation=""`."

So instead you would want to include data-trigger="hover" also looks like your missing a space  before `src=`.

Also you have placement top in the html and also in the javascript. You only need to declare in one place. So you can delete data-placement="top" from the img tag, or in your javascript you can remove it so it would just be `$('.icon').popover({placement:'top'});`

Also you have "`$`" in front of your function. Depending on where that code is located you may have a jquery conflict. To note for sure you'll need to post whichever error you are seeing in your error log. If you use chrome right click > web inspect > click the red x at the bottom and copy any errors you see in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
          $('#poper').popover({
          html: true,
          trigger:'focus',
          content: $('#pop')
          });
          }
        );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this uses the `OnMouseOver` and `OnMouseOut` events described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10709196/121737

I would prefer to do this using one image, the same width as a normal icon but twice the height. This image would show two icons, one above the other, the upper one being the normal icon, the lower being the rolled over icon:

```
img.icon {
    display: block;
    width: 4ex; height: 4ex;
    background-size: 4ex 8ex;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

img.icon:hover {
    background-position: 0 -4ex;
}

img.icon#twitter {
    background-image:url('icons/twitter.jpg');
}

img.icon#facebook {
    background-image:url('icons/facebook.jpg');
}
```

After this declaring the icons in HTML is much cleaner:

```
<img class="icon" id="twitter" />
<img class="icon" id="facebook" />
<img class="icon" style="background-image:url('icons/other_icon.jpg')" />
```